# Ionic conditional ng-src from ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to display the appropriate avator-image based on a person's condition from people on an ng-repeat list. The following code isn't displaying the avator images:

```
$scope.getAvator = function (person) {
  if (person.group_id == 1) {
    return '1.png'
  }
  else if (person.group_id == 2) {
    return '2.png'
  }
  else if (person.group_id == 3) {
    return '3.png'
  };
};
```

AND in the view:

```
<a class="item item-avatar"  ng-repeat="person in people">
    <img ng-src="img/class-avators/{{getAvator}}">
    <h3>{{person.name}}</h3>
    <p>{{person.class }}</p>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with getAvator()

```
<a class="item item-avatar"  ng-repeat="person in people">
    <img ng-src="img/class-avators/{{getAvator(person)}}">
    <h3>{{person.name}}</h3>
    <p>{{person.class }}</p>
</a>
```